# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable while interacting with element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Html snapshot:

[image]

DOM which indicates the cl_login tag is under parent div wrapper class

```
c24-uli-input-wrapper c24-uli-input-wrapper-email c24-uli-input-info style-scope unified-login
```

Locator using xpath:

```
enteremail=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='cl_login']")
```

Output:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Any one help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *`<input>`* element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='cl_login']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='cl_login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```